# I need to find whats the last sql operation done in that database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Mysql and I have a database contains more than 10 tables. 
Now i need to find whats the last sql operation done in that database.. 
example(Any record updated or deleted etc )
Is there any possibilities?

Comment: Are you interested in all queries, or just queries that modify your data? If the latter, look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read this; very helpful article is here

#### http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: Please don't use headline markup to make your links superbold. (That's not what it is for.)

Comment: @MARIO may i know the reason behind that??

Comment: It looks annoying. To be extra blunt, it looks like *attention whoring*. And since your answers are technically correct and interesting, I'd say you aren't in need of that. So please make your answers stand on their own, not on bold markup.

Comment: @mario Thanks for suggestion: i updated my answer; is it fine now ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in data modifications to a particular database, what you can do is utilize the binary log. A binary log, logs all data modifications in files, but for that you have to have binary logging enabled. Then you may use a utility **mysqlbinlog**.

Say for example you have binary logs named,

> mysql-bin.000001
>
> mysql-bin.000001
>
> mysql-bin.000001

Then what you can do is

```
mysqlbinlog -u user_name -p --database=db_name /path/to/binlog/mysql-bin.* > dbqueries.sql
```